# Emailing placement manager my cv directly after having done placement with them

Tags: applications

I did a year long software engineering placement with a company, and I recently noticed that they are advertising a graduate job role. When I had left the company, they said to drop them an email when it was coming up to my graduating in the summer.

I'm not sure whether I should email my previous manager now, attaching my cv etc or whether i should apply online like others would be doing, though my cv might get lost under the rest of the applications? Or should i wait until later in the year, like they said when I left?

I only just found the job posting, but the deadline is tomorrow at 4pm so not sure what the best approach that would help me get noticed without being rude.

Comment: So, you graduate next summer?

Comment: Contacting your previous manager directly is called "networking" and is highly regarded as the best way for both employers and employees to find each other. It is normally good practice to *also* submit your application thru the front door to the same company, so your contact can select you from the pool of applicants instead of presenting you entirely on his own authority.

Comment: Is your graduation coming up? Does the job opening start next summer, or is it meant to start immediately?

Answer (score 1):

I think it definitely makes sense to reach out to your old manager, since he did ask you to reach out. However, I would still follow the normal application process they use for everyone else, then use the email to your manager to point out that you have applied. This means even if the manager isn't involved in the hiring, or isn't interested in helping you out, or is just too slow to make the deadline you are still in the system. However, if he is interested in helping you out, he can talk to the hiring manager or relevant person to maybe bump you up on the stack of applications a bit.

I think if you just email the manager without doing the normal application steps, there are more opportunities to miss out on the chance.

Answer (score 0):

You can email the manager directly. You already have a professional relationship with the manager. It's appropriate to contact them personally.

As you state in your question they've already invited you to do exactly that:

> When I had left the company, they said to drop them an email when it was coming up to my graduating in the summer

I would not interpret the above as "apply online" / "email HR", although you can and probably should do that in addition.

Yes, you should also attach your CV.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should email your manager with CV and cover letter, and let your manager know that you are interested and filing an official application. Let your manager know in your cover letter that you'll be glad to provide any clarification or any additional information needed.
2. File an official application. There's been water flowing under the bridge since you last worked for them, and I expect your application will include the latest and greatest in your work experience. They'll use your official application as point of reference to perform any additional background checks on you that they deem necessary. Don't leave any base uncovered - such as failing to file an official application - as a matter of due diligence.

They said you should wait until later in the year - they probably didn't back then that you'd be available now. The positions are open now, so you should react now. Explain to your manager in your cover letter why you are choosing to apply now.

If you performed well back then, they should be delighted to see you again, as you're a known quantity to them.

Answer (score 0):

Get your CV and resume polished right now and have them prepared to send over.  If you are on good terms with your previous manager, I would call him/her immediately.  Do the usual pleasantries, and then mention you saw the posting on the site and ask for any information about it, specifically ask if the company is looking at summer graduates or if they are looking to fill the position right away.  If they are looking at summer grads, say you are immensely interested, you loved your time there previously, and ask the manager how he/she would recommend you applying.  He/she should be able to guide you from there (might say you can apply as a previous employee or some other method that will potentially give you preference).

If you are unable to get a hold of your manager, send an email right now to him/her with everything mentioned above and also say you are planning on submitting your resume tomorrow.  At least in this case, your previous manager is aware that your resume will be coming and can assist if possible.